# Having trouble switching visibility between divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get this working and I am out of ideas.  I can't use jquery, it needs to be pure javascript/css.  What is wrong with this?

```
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1', 'id2');">Change Payment Method</a>
<div id="id1"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="id2" style="display: none"><p>test 2</p></div>

function toggle_visibility(id1, id2) {  
var e = document.getElementById(id1);
var e2 = document.getElementById(id2);
if(e2.style.display == 'block') {                
  e.style.display = 'block';             
  e2.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
  e.style.display = 'none';            
  e2.style.display = 'block';
}              
}
```

Comment: I'd say ... Nothing -> http://jsfiddle.net/Eeam8/

Comment: Yeah, the code works.

Comment: This code should work as long as your CSS is not overriding the `div` as a block element by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works just! i tried it in my browser

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1', 'id2');">Change Payment Method</a>
        <div id="id1"><p>test 1</p></div>
        <div id="id2" style="display: none"><p>test 2</p></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle_visibility(id1, id2) {  
                var e = document.getElementById(id1);
                var e2 = document.getElementById(id2);
                if(e2.style.display == 'block') {                
                    e.style.display = 'block';             
                    e2.style.display = 'none';
                 }
                 else {
                     e.style.display = 'none';            
                     e2.style.display = 'block';
                 }              
             }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong with your code sample is that you did not enclose your javascript in `<script>` tags.

Example:

```
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1', 'id2');">Change Payment Method</a>
<div id="id1"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="id2" style="display: none"><p>test 2</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id1, id2) {  
        var e = document.getElementById(id1);
        var e2 = document.getElementById(id2);
        if(e2.style.display == 'block') {                
            e.style.display = 'block';             
            e2.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            e.style.display = 'none';            
            e2.style.display = 'block';
        }              
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: It is, I just did not paste that here.

Comment: @Arringar1 - Did you see adeneo's fiddle? Are you getting errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are bad form and not semantically correct. This should be done with CSS class changes:

```
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1', 'id2');">Change Payment Method</a>
<div id="id1" class="ClassThatShows"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="id2" class="ClassThatHides"><p>test 2</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(hideMe, showMe) {  
    document.getElementById(hideMe).className = "ClassThatHides";
    document.getElementById(showMe).className = "ClassThatShows";
} 
</script>
```